# how to create ros-pkg Trac component names for new stacks?

Tags: ros, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need Trac components for these new camera drivers stacks:

- camera1394
- prosilica_driver
- wge100_driver

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12639/how-to-create-ros-pkg-trac-component-names-for-new-stacks?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will get you admin access when i am back at a proper computer

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-01-15**:
access granted